# convert a number to int if it is a whole number else convert to float

Tags: scala

I'm trying to fetch a number from string, then checking if it is a int or double. If it is an integer then I'm converting the number using `toInt`. If it is not then converting to Double using `toDouble`.

```
val str = 50 units
val num = str.split("\\D+").filter(_.nonEmpty)
val y = num(0).toDouble
val x = num(0).toInt
if (x==y) {
  x
  //print("int")
} else {
  y
  //print("double")
}
```

Here is the code I have tried. The problem is even if the condition is true, I'm getting the number converted to double. Can anybody sort out this problem?

Comment: Could you give examples of expected input/output? It's really hard to figure out what's your expected output for what kind of input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st problem** - You're splitting on non-digit characters, so it will split on the point `.` and you'll never get the proper `Double` value.

**2nd problem** - The `x` and `y` variables will *always* be equal because they both come from the same string of digits. `50 == 50.0` is always `true`.

**3rd problem** - Even though the `if` condition is always `true`, and thus always returns the `Int` value in `x`, the result of the `if` is `Double` because an `if` statement has to return a single type. This one tries to return an `Int` **or** a `Double`, so the `Int` value is widened to a `Double` so that the types match.

So what you're trying to do is unsound. You want it to be one type or the other. The type system is trying to enforce a compromise (`Double`). If that's not acceptable you might consider wrapping your types in an `Either`.

```
val numPattern = "\\d*.?\\d+".r
val str = "50 units"
val dbl = numPattern.findFirstIn(str).fold(0.0)(_.toDouble)

val rslt :Either[Int,Double] = if (dbl.isValidInt) Left(dbl.toInt) else Right(dbl)
//rslt: Either[Int,Double] = Left(50)
```

Comment: I understood. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Tricky one

```scala
val res = if (num(0).contains('.')) num(0).toDouble else num(0).toInt
```

Or you can use regex or scala.util.Try.

Answer (score 0):

Your split isn't correct. in case the string is `50.2 units`, `num` will contain `502`. You need to use a proper regex (I only check the first number in the string and it divided by `" "`, in case it exists).

You can do it like this (parsing and finding if it's `int` or `double`)

```
val str = "50.2 units"
val numericRegex: String = ".*\\d+\\.?\\d+.*"
val numOT = Try((str.split(" ").filter(_.matches(numericRegex))).headOption.map(_.toDouble))

numOT match {
  case Success(numO) => 
    numO.fold {
      println(s"no number exist in $str")
    } { num =>
      if ((num % 1) == 0) { 
        println("int") 
      } else { 
        println("double") 
      }
    }
 case Failure(error) => println("an error $error occcurs")  
}
```

You can play with it [here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/GmtXrz7/1)